# NSTableView: problems with title for NSButtonCell

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I have the NSTableView object, that consists from one column with NSButtonCell cell.
Also I have the class, that implements the NSTableViewDataSource protocol.
The method to set the cell value:

```
-( id )tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
    NSButtonCell* cell = [[[NSButtonCell alloc] init] autorelease];
    [cell setTitle:@"Title" ];
    [cell setState:NSOnState];
    return cell;
}
```

In result the state of the button displayed properly but the title stays empty.
How I can set the title of the button?

Comment: Just did a quick search on SO and found **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077875/nsbuttoncell-of-check-type-within-nstableview-does-not-allow-to-have-value-chang)**. Maybe there is something there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this issue by replacing the

```
 NSButtonCell* cell = [[[NSButtonCell alloc] init] autorelease];
```

to

```
NSButtonCell* cell = [tableColumn dataCell];
```